# Passing a source to the next screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, screen, kivymd

The ScreenRecycleView image should be sent to TelaItem when clicking the button on line 174

[Line 174.](https://gist.github.com/CoutinhoElias/25888ad9b1f24cc7353f31f420d13019#file-my_code-py-L174)

In summary: after running the application I will click on the image button and a new screen will be called with the image I chose when I clicked on the button.

I couldn't get this to work.

Comment: Can't follow what exactly you expect to happen.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

when u go from a screenclass to another screenclass u have to use a class variable.

```
class fscreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = 'icon.ong'

class secscreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs):
        self.ids.some_image.source = fscreen.source
```